# Find the node that we will reach with a given path on a graph (complete binary tree)

Tags: graph-theory, trees

**This question is regarding a special case of graph i.e. complete binary tree**

Consider the following tree :-

```
                          1
                    /           \
              2                   3
            /   \                /       \
         4       5               6        7
        / \      /  \          /  \       /  \
       8  9      10 11         12 13      14 15
```

And the Path is given as as combination of L and R

For eg :-

1. Path LLR will be like 1->2->4->9
2. Path RLR will be like 1->3->6->13

Assuming that such a tree is infinite, I need to calculate the node number on a level.
I used the following approach :-

1. Path LLR 
   Length of path is 3 so answer will be at level 4 (since we are starting at root @ level 0)
   LLR taken as L=0 and R=1 becomes 001 = 1 
   And if we assume that one level is a array starting with 0, which in this case is
   [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
   then $1^{st}$ element is to be chosen which is 9 and our answer.
2. Path RLR 
   Length of path is 3 so answer will be at level 4 (since we are starting at root @ level 0)
   RLR taken as L=0 and R=1 becomes 101 = 5 
   And if we assume that one level is a array starting with 0, which in this case is
   [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
   then $5^{th}$ element is to be chosen which is 13 and our answer.

But the problem is that I can have this path length upto 10 power 5. Which makes it difficult for computers to calculate. So, is there a better way to find the needed node on this graph ?

Sorry, for making a mess, I have tried to be as clear as possible. Let me know if I need to change anything in this question. Thanks.

Comment: It is easier for computers (and people) if you use binary numbers for the labeling :)

Comment: Specifically, take $L$ as 0 and $R$ as 1. Then interpret the path $X_1X_2X_3\dots X_n$, where $X_i=L$ or $R$ as the number $1X_1X_2\dots X_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Use binary for the node numbers and for the directions. So if your string of directions (like LLR) is $X_1X_2X_3\dots$, then the node number is $1X_1X_2X_3\dots$ where you take $X_1=0$ for L and $X_1=1$ for R.

Comment: This is what I have done right now but the problem is that path can be up to 10^5 in length which makes the number of bits in binary 10^5 which is difficult to handle in a computer programme

Comment: Well, if your word length is 64 bits, you will need an array or similar structure for the path, but that is not difficult. If your write it sensibly, it should still be fast. In fact with care you can probably use a standard "long integer" library. They are available in several languages.

Comment: The number of bits is 10^5 ? Can you please tell me how did 64 bits come into picture. Pardon me if I sound too naive. Thanks for your time.

Comment: 64 bits is a fairly standard length for the register.

Comment: Well, I am using a 64 bit vector right now. But it does not seem to work for me. Which is why I was looking at a alternate approach.

Comment: Your paths are 100000 long, what structure are you proposing to use to hold them?

Comment: As of now I am using a c++ 11 string assuming that it will take care of this ? Right ?

Comment: You mean a string like LRLLR? That is horrendously inefficient surely (when it comes to extracting information from it)?

Comment: The path is read from a file and comes like that, any suggestions ?

Comment: Is the node numbering also a given? How is that done? There are around $10^{10000}$? Seems bizarrely large.

Comment: Yes, I will compile the actual question and post it here tomorrow. It could be that my approach to solve it is wrong. This is just a part of the big question.